# Difference in appearance of contrast by gender

Tags: production

Watching Casablanca, and I've realized something.  Close-ups of Bogart appear to have high contrast, sharp features.  And close-ups of Bergman are softer, lower contrast, almost fuzzy.

This is certainly not the only film I've seen it in.  Most black and white films have this disparity.  I want to say I've seen it in color films too, but none come to mind.

My question, is this achieved solely through make-up, or are filters used on the camera?

Comment: vaseline on lens?

Comment: Flatter lighting too. Light the guys from one side, light the girls from both, & they really did used to soft-focus a lot on the girls. vaseline, mesh with a hole… There are entire studies of this on many photography sites. I can't hope to cover it in 3 paragraphs on here.

Comment: *"The soft focus effect is used as an effect for glamour photography, because the effect eliminates blemishes, and in general produces a dream-like image."*

Comment: https://prezi.com/j1-zowksywqb/soft-focus-in-classical-hollywood-cinema/

Comment: At some point we need to get this answering business rolling, though.

Comment: Agreed @NapoleonWilson - I just don't know where to start ;)

Comment: The title of this question is not the actual question.

Comment: https://youtu.be/S_nY2kv_oO0?t=205 "Classic cinema lenses on modern cameras"